# Displaying text depending on the value of GET

Tags: php

I made a PHP form and created this error handling script:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET["alert"])) {
        $alert = $_GET["alert"];
        if($_GET["alert"]="nofilled") {
                echo "<div class='error'>You missed something!</div>";
        }
        elseif($_GET["alert"]="badpass") {
                echo "<div class='error'>Your passwords don't match!</div>";
        }
        elseif($_GET["alert"]="badusername") {
                echo "<div class='error'>Your username is too long!</div>";
        }
        elseif($_GET["alert"]="shortpass") {
                echo "<div class='error'>Your password is too short!</div>";
        }
        elseif($_GET["alert"]="takenusername") {
                echo "<div class='error'>That username is taken!</div>";
        }
        elseif($_GET["alert"]="takenemail") {
                echo "<div class='error'>That email already has an account attached to it!</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

I tried to run it with a GET value of 'badpass'. For some reason it echoed the 'nofilled' message.

I'm learning this and I cannot find a solution. Can you have a quick look and see what's wrong?

Comment: It's because you're using `=` instead of `==` in all your `if` GETs

Comment: use == in your conditions

Comment: Or rather instead of `===` which you should always use unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: Or use a `switch()` for switch conditions?

Comment: Thanks, please post as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem happens because you are using one '=' and not '==' (1 is assignment, 2 is comparison).
However, I recommend using the following method since it's more efficient and cleaner:

```
if(isset($_GET["alert"])) {
    $alerts = array(
        "nofilled"=>"You missed something!",
        "badpass"=>"Your passwords don't match!",
        "badusername"=>"Your username is too long!",
        "shortpass"=>"Your password is too short!",
        "takenusername"=>"That username is taken!",
        "takenemail"=>"That email already has an account attached to it!"
        );

    echo "<div class='error'>". isset($alerts[$_GET['alert']]) ? $alerts[$_GET['alert']] : $alerts[$_GET['nofilled']]. "</div>";
}
```

- Per @Tun's correct comment, I added a default fallback to 'nofilled' in case `$alerts[$_GET['alert']])` doesn't exists.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for being the only decent answer IMO. However, make sure you check that the key of the array exists (check my answer to see what I mean).

Comment: good enough! what will happen if `$_GET["alert"]` doesn't exist in the array key? it will be better if it can be checked with `array_key_exist()` and then use it.

Comment: I agree with this answer, it is indeed more efficient and cleaner.

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw very true, I added a fallback to 'nofilled' if it doesn't exists. Cheers! :)

Comment: it should be `'nofilled'` only instead of `$_GET['nofilled']` in the `echo` statement? isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like the situation of using a switch:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["alert"])) {
  echo '<div class = "error">';
  switch($_GET['alert']) {
    case "nofilled": echo "You missed something!"; break;
    case "badpass": echo "Your passwords don't match!"; break;
    ...
    default: echo "An undetermined error ocurred"; break;
    }
  echo '</div>';
  }
```

Or even better (more DRY), simply use an array:

```
if (isset($_GET["alert"])) {
  $Errors = array(
    "nofilled" => "You missed something!",
    "badpass" => "Your passwords don't match!",
    ...
    );
  echo '<div class = "error">';
  if (array_key_exists($_GET['alert'], $Errors))
    echo $Errors[$_GET['alert']];
  else
    echo "An undetermined error ocurred";
  echo '</div>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it defaults to the `'nofilled'` message, is because you're using the `=` assignment operator instead of `==` in all your [conditional statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

`=` is an [`assignment operator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), while `==` is to check if it's "**equal to**" [`comparison operator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

**Rewrite:**

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET["alert"])) {
        $alert = $_GET["alert"];
        if($_GET["alert"]=="nofilled") {
                echo "<div class='error'>You missed something!</div>";
        }
        elseif($_GET["alert"]=="badpass") {
                echo "<div class='error'>Your passwords don't match!</div>";
        }
        elseif($_GET["alert"]=="badusername") {
                echo "<div class='error'>Your username is too long!</div>";
        }
        elseif($_GET["alert"]=="shortpass") {
                echo "<div class='error'>Your password is too short!</div>";
        }
        elseif($_GET["alert"]=="takenusername") {
                echo "<div class='error'>That username is taken!</div>";
        }
        elseif($_GET["alert"]=="takenemail") {
                echo "<div class='error'>That email already has an account attached to it!</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Consult the manual on comparison operators:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

`=` use for assign something

`==` use for comparison

use `==` in your conditions

```
 if(isset($_GET["alert"])) {
            $alert = $_GET["alert"];
            if($_GET["alert"]=="nofilled") {
                    echo "<div class=='error'>You missed something!</div>";
            }
            elseif($_GET["alert"]=="badpass") {
                    echo "<div class=='error'>Your passwords don't match!</div>";
            }
            elseif($_GET["alert"]=="badusername") {
                    echo "<div class=='error'>Your username is too long!</div>";
            }
            elseif($_GET["alert"]=="shortpass") {
                    echo "<div class=='error'>Your password is too short!</div>";
            }
            elseif($_GET["alert"]=="takenusername") {
                    echo "<div class=='error'>That username is taken!</div>";
            }
            elseif($_GET["alert"]=="takenemail") {
                    echo "<div class=='error'>That email already has an account attached to it!</div>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: `$alert == $_GET["alert"];` ??

Comment: good! `$alert = $_GET["alert"];`. you assigned `$alert` variable and never use it??

Comment: don't worry bro its not my code. SO will use it where he needs.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is an assignment operator. Thus `$_GET["alert"]="nofilled"` assigns `"nofilled"` to `$_GET["alert"]`. Instead you should use `===` which is an identity comparison operator. You should not use `==` for comparisons unless you have a strong reason. `==` does automatic type conversion resulting in bugs which are often very hard to detect. Due to the conversion it also is slightly (but of course negligibly) slower.